# OutOfBoundsException with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with my code. I'm writing a program that has to manage weekly squat trainings. There is the possibility to record a previous training or to program a full week. In the second case, for each day, user has to put in the number of squat and the difficulty he thinks it will be. I manage the difficulty of each day with a choicebox that has 3 voices (easy, medium, hard) and when I read the value selected, I save it as an int in order to use it easly for other things in the program (easy=1, medium=2, hard=3).

Now, my problem is that I have 7 choiceBox, one per day, and I need just one method to handle them. Everytime user select a value from one of those choiceBox, it should call the method that scans the value of all the 7 choiceBox and update the relative int values. I adopted this solution because I use only one method for 7 choiceBox and I don't know which one calls the method. To do this, I created a vector of choiceBox and I use a for cicle from 0 to < .length, but everytime I select a voice in any choiceBox, the cicle goes out of bounds. I also created a relative array of int to save the different difficulties.

Here the exception and my method:

***Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7***

```
public void weekDifficulties() {

    for (j = 0; j < arrayCB.length; j++) {

        arrayCB[j].getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                if ((Integer) newValue >= 0 && (arrayCB[j].getItems().get((Integer) newValue).equals("Easy")))
                    arrayDifficulties[j] = "1";
                else if ((Integer) newValue >= 0 && (arrayCB[j].getItems().get((Integer) newValue).equals("Medium")))
                    arrayDifficulties[j] = "2";
                else if ((Integer) newValue >= 0 && (arrayCB[j].getItems().get((Integer) newValue).equals("Hard")))
                    arrayDifficulties[j] = "3";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please specify the exact line where the exception is thrown.  Also - where is `j` defined? If it's a class member then all handlers will have a reference to it, and will all use the value of `arrayCB.length`, which is the value `j` is at after the for loop finishes.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but it would be easier to read your code if `(Integer) newValue` and `arrayCB[j].getItems()` were made into variables before any if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` seems to be a field. In that case when the listeners are triggered, it contains the value last assigned to it, which is `arrayCB.length` = `arrayCB.length` (= the first `int` where the `j < arrayCB.length` yielded `false`). This of course leads to a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Since you obviously need to access the value of the `j` field at the time the loop body is executed, you need to copy it to a variable:

```
for (j = 0; j < arrayCB.length; j++) {
     final int index = j;

    arrayCB[j].getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

            if ((Integer) newValue >= 0 && (arrayCB[index].getItems().get((Integer) newValue).equals("Easy")))
                arrayDifficulties[index] = "1";
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Furthermore `j` probably shouldn't be declared a field in the first place

Comment: Thank you too, same solution of Beniton as I can see. I didn't know the way to work of listeners you told me:  _In that case when the listeners are triggered, it contains the value last assigned to it_ and that's why I wasn't able to give me a sense about OutOfBounds in my code. Thank you very much!

Comment: See also [Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing) and [Accessing Members of an Enclosing Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `arrayCB.length` and `arrayDifficulties.length` are equal otherwise you would get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Else

**EDIT**

Can you store the index j in final variable and use it in the changed method. Possibly it get incremented by the time change Listener notify the method.

Comment: Yes they're equal:

     `String arrayDifficulties[] = new String[7];
    ChoiceBox arrayCB[] = new ChoiceBox[7]; ` indeed I use String not int as I told before

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. I changed int j in final int j but then it gives me error because in `for(j = 0; j < arrayCB.length; j++)` i'm assing a value to a final variable. This is my first experience with javafx and i'm finding some difficulties, this is the biggest and I've tried lots of possible solutions in the last days but with no results

Comment: @Angie No what i meant was like this.  `for (j = 0; j < arrayCB.length; j++) { final int index = j;` and use index inside the changed method. Let me know  if  it works, or otherwise i will try provide you more code.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! Your solution looks quite obviously for me now you told it, as I understood the problem was that j modified his value in the changed method, but I didn't think about using a final variable in this way. thanks for helping!

Comment: Glad it helped you.